# dhcpcd times out at "waiting for carrier"

Tags: wifi, password, timeout, connectivity, dhcpcd

When I try to connect to wifi, dhcpcd gets stuck,

```
# dhcpcd wlxf42853190543
dhcpcd-10.0.6 starting
DUID 00:01:00:01:2d:1b:d8:8a:f4:e8:53:d9:78:b1
wlxf42853190543: waiting for carrier
```

and times out. I cannot connect.

Answer (score 0):

It may simply be a case of using the incorrect wifi password. Update
it and you should then see

```
wlxf42853190543: carrier acquired
wlxf42853190543: connected to Access Point: nibbleston
```

Indeed, in
https://superuser.com/questions/903464/wpa-supplicant-detecting-that-my-password-is-incorrect
we see it is often very hard to get simple notification of such problems.